# Ada: Variant records in which a subset of cases share a common property

Tags: ada

I have the following code in which I'd like for only the first two cases to share a common property; however, I get the error `"id" conflicts with the declaration at line 11` when I try to use this syntax:

```
   type Shape (Which : Shape_Type := SQUARE) is
      record
      case Which is
         when Square =>
            id : Natural;   -- Line 11
         when Turnout =>
            id : Natural;   -- Line that causes error to be thrown
         when Invalid =>
            null;
      end case;
      end record;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
type Shape (Which : Shape_Type := SQUARE) is
   record
      case Which is
         when Square | Turnout =>
            id : Natural;
         when Invalid =>
            null;
      end case;
   end record;
```

If you later wanted the `Turnout` case to have an extra attribute, you could do that using a nested `case` (but you still have to cover all the alternatives):

```
type Shape (Which : Shape_Type := SQUARE) is
   record
      case Which is
         when Square | Turnout =>
            id : Natural;
            case Which is
               when Square =>
                  null;
               when Turnout =>
                  Deg : Natural;
               when Invalid =>
                  null;
            end case;
         when Invalid =>
            null;
      end case;
   end record;
```

Comment: +1 for the nested casings; I didn't know you could do that, but it looks awesome/clever (in the good way, rather than the scratch-your-head/WTF-was-I-thinking kicking yourself in 6 months).